# Mediapipe: How to configure debugger? (using VS Code and Bazel)

Tags: mediapipe

Does anyone know how to effectively debug mediapipe?

So far I'm putting print statements in every second line and keep on compiling + running the code until I find my errors.

Is there any way to debug this using breakpoints and a debugger, say from VS code?

I already saw that vs code features a Bazel extension, however I'm not sure how to configure the extension properly.

This is what I normally run in terminal in the root directory to compile and run

```
bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu

bazel run --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu --calculator_graph_config_file=mediapipe/graphs/hand_tracking/hand_tracking_desktop_signn.pbtxt
```

Further info:
[image]
There apparantly is already a bazel plugin installed in vs code. This is what the vs code bazel plugin settings look like. While I could find a potential candidate for my executable, I'm not sure about the 'buildifier'. Is this a normal  bazel compiler? I'm currently using bazelisk, which is supposed to figure out the required bazel version automatically. Could I just use the bazelisk executable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick answer: Adding this content as into `.vscode/launch.json` allows me to debug mediapipe with breakpoints:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "preLaunchTask": "Bazel Build (Debug)",
        "name": "CodeLLDB",
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "console": "internalConsole", 
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking/hand_tracking_cpu",
        "args": ["--calculator_graph_config_file=mediapipe/graphs/hand_tracking/hand_tracking_desktop_signn.pbtxt"],
        "env": {"GLOG_logtostderr":"1"},
        "sourceMap": {
          "/proc/self/cwd/": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
      }
    ]
  }
```

Notes

- I'm still building via command line using `-c dbg` as additional argument to compile a binary that is suited for usage with the debugger
- CodeLLDB is a extension that has to be installed beforehand (see vscode extensions).
- `"env": {"GLOG_logtostderr":"1"}` is a system variable (similar to $PATH in linux), that tells the debugger to write Google logger output to console
- `/bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/` is the location of the binary file once you compile with bazel using debug flags ( -c dbg )
- other command line arguments go into `"args"` as you can see by comparing with the original launch command
- `"/proc/self/cwd/": "${workspaceFolder}"` is needed so the debugger breaks in the correct file (by default, the debugger opens different source files than those where you actually put the break point

**Update**
In case you also want the build to be executed by vscode you need to add the following entry to your `.vscode/tasks.json`

```
    {
        "label": "Bazel Build (Debug)",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "bazel build -c dbg --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
    }
```

Note how the label "Bazel Build (Debug)" corresponds to "preLaunchTask" in launch.json

Comment: The app is launched successfully but no breakpoint is triggered. Any suggestion?

Comment: did you compile with debug symbols flag? (-c dbg)

Comment: Yes, with the -c dbg flag.